# Is there any public server I can use to synchronyze Tomboy?

Tags: 16.04, tomboy

I'm using Tomboy on my notebook and Tomdroid on my phone. I would like notes between these two to be synchronized. Both apps have the capability to sync using an online server, as it was back in the days of Ubuntu One. Is there any public server available I can use to do this? I don't want to install Rainy myself.

Best regards.